# How to Select checkbox in Appium using Python if there is no unique ID/Text/Class name

Tags: appium, python-appium

[Elements which i need to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbCaM.png)

[Element loator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La2F8.png)

Hi I am trying to click checkbox.
the below is my code

```
from appium import webdriver
```

import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

desired_cap = dict(

```
platformName="Android",
platformVersion="11",
deviceName="1234567",
appPackage="io.appium.android.apis",
appActivity="io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos"
```

)
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", desired_cap)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Accessibility']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//android.widget.TextView[@text='Accessibility Node Querying']").click()
time.sleep(2)
chk= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//android.widget.CheckBox")

for i in chk:
if i == 2:
i.click()

By above code if i give i.click() i am able to click all checkboxes. But if i want to click single check box i am not getting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Select an array of elements and tap on its index

```
elements = self.driver.find_elements(*locator)
        elements[i].click()
```